# How do I disable my zoom functionality in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scroll, zooming

I have a zoom functionality made in D3, but I'd like to make it optional, so I'd like a way to turn it off. Here's my code:

```
//Zoom command ...
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(xScale)
    .y(yScale)
    .scaleExtent([1,10])
    .on("zoom", zoomTargets);

var SVGbody = SVG.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .call(zoom);
```

/

```
/The function handleling the zoom. Nothing is zoomed automatically, every elemnt must me defined here.
function zoomTargets() {
    if($("#enableZoom").is(':checked')){    
        var translate = zoom.translate(),
        scale = zoom.scale();

        tx = Math.min(0, Math.max(width * (1 - scale), translate[0]));
        ty = Math.min(0, Math.max(height * (1 - scale), translate[1]));

        //This line applies the tx and ty which prevents the graphs from moving out of the limits. This means it can't be moved until zoomed in first.
        zoom.translate([tx, ty]);

        SVG.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .style("font-size", AXIS_FONTSIZE)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-30)" 
                });

        SVG.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
                .style("font-size", AXIS_FONTSIZE);

        SVG.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale(graphDataX[i]);})
        .attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(d);});

        SVGMedian.selectAll("ellipse")
            .attr("cx", function(d, i){ return xScale((i*100)+100);})
            .attr("cy", function(d){ return yScale(d-0.01);});
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried using an if-statement to prevent the zoom functionality from working when a checkbox isn't ticked. This prevents users from scrolling on the page when the mouse is inside of the SVG frame.

I'd like the correct way to do this. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: If you want dragging but no zooming, ignore `zoom.scale()`.

Comment: I want everything disabled. My website has some content so you are able to scroll on the entire page (not just the SVG). When I "turn off" my zoom with that if-statement i can't scroll on the page anymore when the mouse is in the SVG area for some reason. I'd like to be able scroll like on any regular page when it's disabled.

Comment: Well it sounds like something is happening with the zoom behaviour. Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: Yes, I have a similar code here: http://jsfiddle.net/RBr8h/12/ At first you can't zoom, when the checkbox isn't ticked. And you can't scroll down the page itself either, which is what I want to be able to do. When the checkbox is ticked, you can zoom as you are supposed to. It seems to me that if the zoom.behaviour is set to anything it steals mouse control from the browser so i can't scroll on the page itself.

Comment: I can scroll the page in your example just fine.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it again. You CAN scroll, but only if the mouse is out of the SVG region: http://puu.sh/8JfqM.png

Comment: Works fine for me in both case on Chrome.

Comment: That's very odd. I'm using chrome too. I've tried with Safari and IE aswell. When I hold the mouse over the graph I cannot scroll down the page at any time. I don't understand how it could possibly work S:

Answer (score 3):

This is a way to disable d3 zoom behavior

```
SVGbody.select("g").call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", null));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It doesn't work for me though, I think its because I have several places where I use `append("g")`. How can I implement it if this is how the generated html looks like? http://puu.sh/8Jggo.png I tried giving putting `.attr("class", "zoomClass")` and using `selectAll(".zoomClass")` instead of `select("g")`, but it still doesn't make any different, the zoom still works afterwards.

Comment: SVGbody.select("g") returns the first descendant g element. May be the element with zoom may not be the first child. If that g has a class, bind call using select method. Can u make a JsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RBr8h/12/ I have one here. It has several G elements and i use `call(zoom)` on one of them. I use it on two in my full code, but I presume that using a class attribute will grab both of them.

Comment: I checked, the g I want to select is indeed not the first child. It's the 2nd and the last one that I want to select on my original code.

Comment: So, this means the answer is correct, no? (because selecting "g" is not essential part of the answer...)